# Keyboard input is not working in Firefox ALONE

Tags: windows-7, firefox, keyboard

This has never happened before. I went through the following steps in trying to solve the problem:

- I was initially using Firefox beta. I updated it but that did not solve the problem.
- Uninstalled Firefox beta and installed the mainline version and made sure to check for both Firefox and Windows updates. Problem still persisted.
- Restarted Firefox with all add-ons disabled. Problem still persisted.
- Restarted Firefox in safe mode. Problem still persisted.

I'm frustrated and stranded. I'm running on Windows 7 Professional 64-bit.

Comment: Does on screen keyboard work?

Comment: @user3169 I didn't think to try that. However uninstalling, rebooting and installing again fixed the issue. Still no explanation why it happened though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling, rebooting and reinstalling solved the issue. Still don't know why it happened though.